# Can I search on Date "Today" in Amazon AWS EC2 Mangement Console

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to get a list of instances in the Amazon AWS EC2 Mangagement Console which is filtered on Launch Time before today. With the new Management Console update it's easier than ever (see screenshot below) to do advanced searches including inversion and all, but I did not figure out yet how to search on the date of `Today` rather than `September 3, 2014 00:00:00 AM UTC`.

Can this be done, and how?

[image: screenshot 1]

---

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The Management Console can not interpret "Today".  There is no AWS keyword for Today, and  it's not possible with Regular Expressions because regex does not have a concept of time; it can only validate patterns.